# How is it valid that a question considers another question a duplicate, but that other question was considered off topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252588/why-are-deadlines-always-so-short?noredirect=1&lq=1) cites two duplicates, one of which is [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206475/are-missed-deadlines-common-in-programming-jobs), which was closed as off topic, with the specific reason "primarily opinion-based".

I don't hang out much in this SE, but usually that close reason implies that the question is not answerable, will have little value to other people or situations, and will attract low quality answers.

If the question is being referenced as a duplicate with a valid answer, shouldn't it be re-opened?

I'm not following the logic behind all of that, so if you could break it down barney style ([explanation 1](https://terminallance.com/2015/03/20/terminal-lance-371-barney-style/), [2](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/barney-style), [3](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=barney%20style)), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: See also: [Why was my question closed as "Primarily Opinion-Based?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/) Together with that info, your question is almost duplicate of [your other recent Meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8785/60357) where I discuss some background of closing questions.

Answer (score -3):

I think the duplicate thing is incorrectly used when it refers to a question with no accepted answer or a closed question or a question itself marked as duplicate.

We end up with weird referral loops which don't provide an answer to the question that's being asked.